# Forwarding keyEvents from one window to another

Tags: wpf

I'd like to bring the keydown events from a popup window-object to the hosting window-object.

The popup is able to get a reference to the hosting window-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass events from one UIElement to another, you can use the [`RaiseEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent.aspx) method. There are a number of ways to do this, but this one is fairly simple. If you want to learn more about the concept, take a look at [this overview on Routed Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).

In popup window:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnKeyDown(e);

  var window = // reference to hosting window

  window.RaiseEvent(e);
}
```

In hosting window body:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnKeyDown(e);

  // use the key event
}
```

Comment: tyvm .. i'll try that out tomorrow ... but it seems to be correct :)